# What is the scope of the classspath defined in a the manifest of a Java jar file

Tags: java, log4j, executable-jar

I'm trying to deploy a small app that uses log4j.  The app is deployed as an executable jar with a manifest that contains a Class-Path attribute.
This is accomplished with the Ant jar task.  Here is the line that defines the Class-Path

```
<attribute name="Class-Path" value=" ./ islib  islib/commons-lang-2.0.jar islib/commons-logging-1.0.jar islib/log4j-1.2.16.jar" >
```

The executable jar is deployed and run from C:/ami/bin.  log4j.properties cannot be found if it is in C:/ami/bin/islib but is found if it is in C:/ami/bin.
All other jars in /islib are found and the app runs normally.

Does the Class-Path in the manifest define a classpath only for the classes in the jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Classpath defines where the class loader should find classes.

Log4j.properties is NOT read from the Classpath but from the file system, I.e. Relative to the current directory when the program is started.

(Logback looks for its configuration file in the Classpath in case you use slf4j as the logging API)